# How to traverse these functions as required

Tags: list-manipulation

We know that the function f can take x, x^2, x^3 in turn.

What can I do to traverse {f [0], f [1], f '[1]} and get `{{0, 1, 1},{0, 1, 2},{0, 1, 3}}`?

```
Outer[Construct, {1 &, #1 &, #1^2 &, #1^3 &}, {0, 1, 1}]
```

The above code cannot take the value of `f'[1]`. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way.

```
Clear["`*"];
Table[Flatten@{f[0], 
   Through[{f, Derivative[1][f]}[1]]}, {f, {# &, #^2 &, #^3 &}}]
```

Comment: `Outer[{#[0], #[1], #'[1]} &, {# &, #^2 &, #^3 &}]`

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
Outer[Construct,
    {#[0]&,#[1]&,#'[1]&},
    {#&, #^2&, #^3&}
] // Transpose
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{#[0], #[1], #'[1]} & /@ (Function[x, #] & /@ {x, x^2, x^3})
```

> ```
> {{0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 3}}
> ```

Also

```
Map[{#[0], #[1], #'[1]} & @* (Function[x, #] &)] @ {x, x^2, x^3}
```

> ```
> {{0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 3}}
> ```